# Execute a plugin-installed WP-CLI command with Docker Compose

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, wp-cli

**Intro:**

I am trying to run a few WP-CLI commands for maintenance as a part of my release process on my production sites. I can execute the following commands against the docker-compose file below successfully.

- `docker-compose run wp-cli_collinmbarrett-com core update`
- `docker-compose run wp-cli_collinmbarrett-com plugin update --all`
- `docker-compose run wp-cli_collinmbarrett-com theme update --all`
- `docker-compose run wp-cli_collinmbarrett-com db optimize`

I have a plugin ([WP-Sweep](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-sweep/)) installed on the site that adds its own WP-CLI command. When I try to run this command, [it fails](https://dev.azure.com/collinbarrett/wp-host-on-containers/_releaseProgress?_a=release-environment-deployment-group-logs&releaseId=766&environmentId=766&deploymentGroupPhaseId=790).

```
docker-compose run wp-cli_collinmbarrett-com sweep --all
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 15: sweep: not found
```

In a non-dockerized setup, I have verified that the WP-Sweep command for WP-CLI works successfully.

**Question:**

How can I run plugin-installed WP-CLI commands when running in a containerized environment with Docker Compose? Do I need to somehow make the WP-CLI container aware of the installed plugins other than having a shared volume?

**My `docker-compose.yml`:**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  wp_collinmbarrett-com:
    image: wordpress:fpm-alpine
    restart: always
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy
      - collinmbarrett-com
    depends_on:
      - mariadb_collinmbarrett-com
    volumes:
      - collinmbarrett-com_files:/var/www/html

  mariadb_collinmbarrett-com:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      - collinmbarrett-com
    volumes:
      - collinmbarrett-com_data:/var/lib/mysql

  wp-cli_collinmbarrett-com:
    image: wordpress:cli
    networks:
      - collinmbarrett-com
    volumes:
      - collinmbarrett-com_files:/var/www/html

networks:
  reverse-proxy:
    external:
      name: wp-host_reverse-proxy
  collinmbarrett-com:

volumes:
  collinmbarrett-com_files:
  collinmbarrett-com_data:
```

Full config on [GitHub](https://github.com/collinbarrett/wp-host-on-containers).

Comment: DId you ever figure a workaround for this? Re the installing of the sweep plugin, i suspect you need to download the plugin zip to the container. The wp-cli assumes the plugin is available via the wp-cli package list which i guess sweep isn't.

Comment: I didn't. Maybe so. It's not really a need I have any more, but would love to hear of a working solution regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering directly to your command needs (I didn't tried yet), but I wanted to share with you all the configurations I'm using in hope it helps you.

My `docker-compose.yml` has:

```
services:
...
  # Mysql container
  db:
...
  # Wordpress container
  wp:  
...
  wpcli:
    image: wordpress:cli
    user: "33:33"
    volumes:
      # necessary to write to the filesys
      - ./php-config/phar.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/phar.ini
      - wp_app:/var/www/html
      - /tmp/wp-temp:/tmp/wp-temp
    environment:
      HOME: /tmp/wp-temp
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: $WORDPRESS_DB_USER
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: $WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: $WORDPRESS_DB_NAME
    depends_on:
      - db
      - wp
volumes:
  wp_app: {}
...
```

Please note that as mentioned on **Running as an arbitrary user** section in https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress:

> When running WP-CLI via the cli variants of this image, it is
> important to note that they're based on Alpine, and have a default
> USER of Alpine's www-data, whose UID is 82 (compared to the
> Debian-based WordPress variants whose default effective UID is 33), so
> when running wordpress:cli against an existing Debian-based WordPress
> install, something like --user 33:33 is likely going to be necessary
> (possibly also something like -e HOME=/tmp depending on the wp command
> invoked and whether it tries to use ~/.wp-cli)

You will need to define WP-CLI user as www-data with user id and group id = 33. This is why I defined `user: "33:33"`. Also, the command might need to download temporary content, so I defined a `HOME` environment setting. Please also note that `HOME` mapped **in your Host** should also be assigned with user 33:33 ownership ids, otherwise WP CLI can't write to the filesys.

Also, PHP.ini in the WPCLI image has the setting `phar.readonly` as `On`, so you need to override it. I've add a specific `./php-config/phar.ini` file that has that override:

```
phar.readonly = Off
```

To execute a plugin installation I do, on my `docker-compose.yml` folder, the following command:

```
docker-compose run --rm wpcli plugin install wp-mail-smtp  --force --allow-root
```

Please note that  `--force --allow-root` are optional.